# Running automation script through gitlab

Tags: maven, automation, gitlab, automated-tests, gitlab-ci

I am trying to run my automation script through gitlab via .yml file with below code

```
stages:
    - test

test :
    stage : test
    image : maven:latest
    script: 
        - mvn test -Dtestng=tesng.xml
```

it is giving me error

```
($ mvn test -Dtestng=tesng.xml
bash: line 152: mvn: command not found
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1)
```

how to install mvn on gitlab?

any help would be appreciated

Comment: What type of executor is your runner using?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.